# .csv file reading in mfc

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am reading .csv file in MFC. This file contains header and data values. How to skip header part during reading time.

[image]

```
    if(TRUE == file.Open(filename, CFile::modeRead | CFile::typeText, &fileError)) 
    {           
        while(1) 
        {
            if(file.ReadString(strLine) == FALSE)
            {
                break;
            }


            ..///////////////////////////////////
        }
        file.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Just read the first line and forget it! What is your question? How do you read the file? Pleas show code...

Comment: @xMRi I have added part of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(TRUE == file.Open(filename, CFile::modeRead | CFile::typeText, &fileError)) 
{           
    file.ReadString(strLine);
    while(file.ReadString(strLine)) 
    {


        ..///////////////////////////////////
    }
    file.Close();
}
```

Comment: You aren't evaluating the return value of the first `ReadString` invocation. I'd suggest `if ( file.Open( ... ) && file.ReadString( strLine ) )` instead. `ReadString` can throw exceptions under certain (undocumented) conditions. Without evaluating the return value, the code may be semantically different.

Comment: This may be the case, or it may not be. It is not documented what happens when you read from a stream when it's already in a fail state.

Comment: It is. It is at EOF. Any further call to ReadFile will do nothing, than an immediate return...

Comment: You are relying on undocumented behavior. The MFC implementation you are currently using happens to expose the behavior you describe. Nonetheless, this is not part of the contract, and should not be relied upon. Something is very wrong, when you have to explain this to an MVP.

Comment: CStdioFile uses ReadString and ReadString checks EOF first.  
And even if not. CStdioFile relies on the standard _tfopen and _fgetts. fegts itself just._fgetts  itself uses _fgettc (_fgettc_nolock). And again rechecks the EOF condition before it access a buffer. I also debugged ReadFile it also returns EOF when the file pointer reaches the end. And even the documentation says nothing else. No data is returned when EOF is reached.

Comment: Yes it is not clearly mentioned, but there are hundreds of things we relay on, that are not 100% documented in detail. Implementation may change? Yes. But if everything that is not documented may change, we are lost :) If you can keep your code free from such side effects, I can't. Also blame it on my native tongue that I understand things as I do.... :) I apologies the noise that I caused in trying to answer such questions. If you think we need a further discussion feel free to send me an email.